# For Loop in Foreach Loop Performance Improvement

Tags: c#, performance, for-loop, foreach

I have a db table with 2M entries

My XPositions table structure is

```
Id - int
FID - int
CoordinateQue - int
Latitude - float
Longitude - float
```

Each row represents a marker position and I need to calculate distance between each coordinates and save to another table.

My xWeights table structure is;

```
Id - int
x_Id - int
Tox - int
Distance - decimal(18,8)
```

So far my working code is

```
var query = _xRepository.TableNoTracking;
var xNodes = query.ToList()
var n = new xWeights();

foreach (var x in xNodes)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < xNodes.Count; i++)
    {
        if(x.Id == xNodes[i].Id)
        {
            //Do nothing - Same Node
        }
        else
        { 
        var R = 6378137; 
        var φ1 = (Math.PI / 180) * x.Latitude;
        var φ2 = (Math.PI / 180) * xNodes[i].Latitude;
        var Δφ = (xNodes[i].Latitude - x.Latitude) * (Math.PI / 180);
        var Δλ = (xNodes[i].Longitude - x.Longitude) * (Math.PI / 180);
        var Δψ = Math.Log(Math.Tan(Math.PI / 4 + φ2 / 2) / Math.Tan(Math.PI / 4 + φ1 / 2));
        var q = Math.Abs(Δψ) > 10e-12 ? Δφ / Δψ : Math.Cos(φ1); // E-W course creates problem with 0/0
        // if Longitude over 180° take shorter rhumb line across the anti-meridian:
        if (Math.Abs(Δλ) > Math.PI) Δλ = Δλ > 0 ? -(2 * Math.PI - Δλ) : (2 * Math.PI + Δλ);
        var dist = (Math.Sqrt(Δφ * Δφ + q * q * Δλ * Δλ)) * R;

        n.x_Id = x.Id;
        n.Tox = xNodes[i].Id;
        n.Distance = dist;

            _xWeightsRepository.Insert(n);
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is; I am getting approximately 35k records per minute so will be 2.1M record per hour. This will take forever to finish this. Any ideas how to improve the performance?

Comment: Yes. Stop doing the calculation row by agonizing row. You should do this directly in t-sql. Then think about what you need to do to a column and not what you want to do to each row. But you said you have 2 million rows and it will take an hour to complete. That isn't forever unless this is behind a button click or something that is in the application. ;)

Comment: I have no idea how to do it in sql. Unfortunately it is in application. yes I have 2M records which will pair with 2M records. So this way it will almost take 2M hours :)

Comment: You're funny. You complain that it takes so long, when you perform **ONE** insert operation per inner loop? Of course it takes forever, what did you expect?

Comment: @Tseng what is your suggestion? Adding to a list and do the insert that way?

Comment: It may be one improvement. Please note that `.AddRange` is much more performant than `.Add` because it invokes the change tracker only once, rather than on every call. However, the fact alone that you are fetching 2m records into memory requires considerable amount of time (transferiing and serializing the data), then adding it back consumes more memory too (because of tracking done by DbContext). Most performant is indeed to perform it on database and insert it there too (stored procedure). If you are willing to move business logic there is a different topic

Comment: I am really bad on stored procedures. just basic stuff on sql :) Have no idea how to do it...

Comment: How often do you have to do this? PS You could set `n.x_Id` in the outside loop.

Comment: @NetMage probably once in my lifetime and never again :)))

Comment: Yeah for a one off thing who cares? You have something that works, just run it during a maintenance window.

Comment: @SeanLange I will need to wait for 2M hours to complete :) I don't think I will live that long :) 228 years :)

Comment: @Tseng I tried adding to list but since I have a lot records I had out of memory exception :)

Comment: Adding to list then insert made it slower. any ideas how can I do it in sql?

Comment: @BulutKartal Are you using LINQ to SQL or Entity Framework 6 or EF Core? Did you do `AddRange` to the `DBSet`? See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5942176/2557128) answer.

Comment: @NetMage I use Entity Framework 6, I will check, Ty!

Comment: I used .BulkInsert(List) it is a huge improvement but still not good enough. Reduced to 3 years from 228 years:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not with this function, but with what you are trying to achieve.

You are trying to insert every from-to combination into _xWeightsRepository. If there are 2 million nodes, then that means 4 thousand billion weights.

If you could insert a weight per CPU clock cycle (which is several orders of magnitude faster than you could ever actually hope to achieve) then you'll still be waiting ten or twenty years.

Check out SQL spatial indexes. I'm going to take a guess that your answer lies in that direction:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-spatial-index-transact-sql

Comment: I guess I will go with unweighted approach :)